# ¿Cómo uso una variable PHP dentro de un SQL Query?

Tags: php, sql, variables

Soy muy nuevo en *SQL* y estoy desarrollando un proyecto utilizando *PHP* y *MySQL*. ¿Cómo puedo incluir una variable para obtener información seleccionada de la tabla?

Este es el código que tengo:

```html
<div class="section">
  <?php
    $sql='SELECT * FROM users WHERE Patrocinador = $_SESSION['NumCedula']';
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    //echo [$result];
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  ?>
      <div class="mis_afiliados_1">
        <a> 
          <img src="<?php echo $row['avatar'];?>" alt="Avatar" style="max-width:90px;max-height:auto; border-radius:50%; border:2px #000 solid;" /><br>   
        <?php
          echo $row['nombre'];
        ?><br>
        <?php echo date('d/m/Y',$row['signup_date']); ?></a><br>
      </div>
      <?php
    }
  ?>
</div>
```

Obviamente la variable `$_SESSION['NumCedula']` no funciona, solo necesito que reconozca la información almacenada en la celda `NumCedula` de la base de datos para que funcione. ¿Cómo lo hago?

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Podrías traducir tu pregunta? // If you'd like to ask in English, please remove your question by clicking on "eliminar" and ask on [so]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes acceder a las variables si las colocas entre corchetes `{}`

```
<?php
  $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Patrocinador = {$_SESSION['NumCedula']}";
?>
```

Comment: Wow gracias; pero ahora me sale este error:  Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/fareleon/public_html/ecuador/mi-red.php on line 19

Comment: Para usar variables incrustadas en Strings es **necesario** que el string sea con **comillas dobles**

Comment: @MáximaAlekz gracias, se edito la respuesta.

Answer (score 5):

Según lo que conozco de PHP hay 2 formas sencillas de hacerlo:

**Usando un . (punto):**

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM users WHERE Patrocinador = '.$_SESSION['NumCedula'].'';
```

Pero, es **nada** seguro. Deja una puerta muy abierta a inyecciones SQL.

**Usando {}**

Para ello **hay que usar** comillas dobles.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Patrocinador = {$_SESSION['NumCedula']}";
```

Aun, este metodo es tan inseguro como el primero.

Te recomiendo que apliques una proteccion almenos del nivel 1 como lo es usar htmlentities():

```
$numCedula = htmlentities($_SESSION['NumCedula'],ENT_QUOTES,'utf-8');
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Patrocinador = {$numCedula}";
```

Esto cambiara simbolos como `<>"'` a entidades HTML, el resultado de esos 4 simbolos seria el siguiente: `&lt;&gt;&quot;&apos;` asi que de esta forma, el atacante tendra menos posibilidades de hacerse con tu informacion :)

Comment: Excelente respuesta Máxima Alekz .. se te agradecece enormemente!!

Comment: Si te ha funcionado por favor, marcala como respuesta :) Eso se hace dando click en el signo ✓